# Does $1-1+1/2-1/2+1/3-1/3+\cdots$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Is this true the the above series converge? What might be a economic way to show this? I tried to rearrange them but it seems like they are not all positive so its a bit dangerous. So it is alternating, How will you show this? Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: Hint: telescoping sums

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The partial sum is either $0$ or $\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$. And both $0$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$

Comment: +1: in a similar vein, if there are $n$ terms then the partial sum is $\frac{2}{n+1}$ or $0$ depending on whether $n$ is odd or even, i.e. $\frac{1 -(-1)^n}{n+1}$.

Comment: @Henry why $\frac{2}{n+1}$?

Comment: The sum of the first one term is $1$ which is $\dfrac{2}{1+1}$. The sum of the first three terms is $\dfrac12$ which is $\dfrac{2}{3+1}$. The sum of the first five terms is $\dfrac13$ which is $\dfrac{2}{5+1}$ and similarly for other odd numbers

Comment: @Henry ah ok, I see what you mean :)

Comment: But how do you rigorously show that The partial sum is either $0$ or $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Kun, it's enough to compute directly by the definition of partial sum

Comment: Can you write it out please... I just really confused

Comment: @Kun  we have $S_{2n} = 1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} = 0$ and $S_{2n+1} = 1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$